# Format multiple date entries as strings

Tags: string, excel, datetime

I have an Excel file storing a thousand lines of dates. Each date seems to be (auto)formatted as a Date. A (PHP Excel) parser I'm using (really can't update/use another one) is parsing this to a string which will occur in the number of days till 1900.

Is there a way to format the values in Excel being simple text "08.03.1991" to get this file parsed correctly?

I could add a quote: "'08.03.1991" but **I need an (Excel-based) one-action-solution for all the thousand lines**.

**Remark**: Since this is a file of a user I can't just write simple VBA-Script or so to handle this since there will be new files in the future and the User needs to be able to solve this alone.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636157/excel-date-to-string-conversion)

Comment: Sorry i dont see any solution for applying that to multiple rows at ones. (Without a VBA-Script)

Comment: Insert a new column, write the formula at the top, copy to the whole column. Is it manageable by your user? There is also the dumb solution: copy the column to Notepad++, use its find/replace feature to add a quote at the beginning of each line, and copy back to Excel, but I prefer the first one.

Comment: Or, to keep things as simple as possible: copy the whole column to any text editor (notepad will be enough), copy back to Excel, but use the Import Wizard to tell you want data as "text", not as "standard"

Comment: Excel will still autoformat this as date, whether I choose "text" or "unicode/text"

Comment: My Excel (2010) doesn't. When I check with the [CELL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/cell-function-HP010062392.aspx) function (for "type"), it tells me it's a string.

Comment: To reproduce my problem: open a new excel file and fill in some dates like "08.03.1991". Excel now will automatically format this as "date". If I need this as a string I right-click on the cell to format it and choose "Text" or "Default" which does occur in "33305".

If I write a new excel its easy if I knew this before to keep it as string, now the problem is there's already an excel file with 1000 lines formatted as date.

Comment: Use the **Convert Text to Columns Wizard**. See for example [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/trois-manieres-de-convertir-des-nombres-en-texte-HA001136619.aspx).

Comment: Great! This did the job.

Comment: Then you should accept pnuts's answer, as it's exactly his answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit I am not quite sure what you have and what you want but it may be worth trying: Select column of dates, apply Text to Columns with Tab as delimiter and in step 3 of 3 select Text.

Comment: Formatting the cells as Text does occur in "33306" e.g. instead of "09.03.1991"

Comment: Yes! The same Wizard as copy to notepad and back, but without the need to copy. Nice trick :-) At least with my Excel, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `TEXT` function like this:

```
=TEXT(A1,"dd.mm.yyyy")
```

For more details have a look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx)

Comment: But this would require me to edit ALL lines separately, right?

Comment: @xcy7e Not really separately. If a column has dates, you write the formula once and you copy it in only one copy/paste, or autofill.

Comment: you just click in the right corner of the cell in which you put the formula and drag down and it will autofill

Comment: I need to replace the values not add a second column containing the data of the previous column to be reformatted. I really need to replace the messed up excel date-format with a simple string. Is this not possible with Excel?