# Convert date to string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have an excel that has a column filled with date objects in this form: 20/12/2016.

I would like to convert them to string values of this form: 20161220, how could I achieve that?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your regional setting for short date? What order? DMY or MDY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637156/1270789), simply:

```
=TEXT(A1,"YYYYDDMM")
```

Should do the trick.

Verified on Excel 2010.

However, the letters to use for the day, month, and year are locale-dependent; for instance German is:

```
=TEXT(A1;"JJJJMMTT")
```

And Greek is:

```
=TEXT(A1;"εεεεμμηη")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm using Excel 2013, the above doesn't work. I tried 
`=TEXT(A1;"YYYYDDMM")` 
but it returns YYYYDDMM

Comment: @jenny are sure these dates are Dates ? (not strings looking like dates)

Comment: @KenY-N Strings as dates will only work if Excel can interpret them as dates. If the MM and DD are in the wrong order for a day higher than 12, Excel won't recognize it as a date.

Comment: @jenny: The format patterns in the `Text` function are locale dependent. With `German` locale it must be `=TEXT(A1;"JJJJMMTT")`.

Comment: @Axel I'm using greek locale, so you are right in my case it should be like this: `=TEXT(A1;"εεεεμμηη")`

Comment: Updated the answer based on your comments, and made it a Community Wiki post.

Comment: @Ken Y-N: Should be in English `=TEXT(A1,"YYYYMMDD")` since needed is 20161220 which is 4 digits year 2 digits month 2 digits day.

Comment: I tried both, only the semicolon works for me. With the comma, I get an error from excel saying there was a problem with formula

Comment: @jenny: Whether comma or semicolon is used as delimiter in formulas is also locale dependent. Some locales use semicolon because the comma is decimal separator already.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

=YEAR(A1)&MONTH(A1)&DAY(A1)

This is evaluated by Excel as a text string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work in every case. For a date like this: 20/12/2016 it outputs this: 20161220, but for a date like this: 01/09/2016 it outputs that: 201691

Comment: I get the same results

Comment: @Vitor Barreto: `=TEXT(YEAR(A1),"0000")&TEXT(MONTH(A1),"00")&TEXT(DAY(A1),"00")` would be the solution which is most locale independent.