# MS Excel date conversion

Tags: excel

I got CSV report that has dateTime stamp on it (2020-10-26T18:32:21Z) MS Excel does not recognize it as the date, is there an easy way to get MS recognize as DATE data type?

Thank you

Comment: you will need to parse the data to a recognizable string.  This particular format to date parse has been answered many times on this site.

Comment: `=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," "),"Z","")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Date to String conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636157/excel-date-to-string-conversion)

Comment: @Adam that is the reverse of what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in **A1**, try:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))
```

[image]

*a slight change would be needed if you also needed the time `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))`*